# VS2017: why cannot select Azure Functions for NetCore?

Tags: azure, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

So I researched a lot about trying to create an Azure Functions project. Downloaded latest extensions, updated my VS2017 community, etc.

I still only get two options NetFw and NetStandard.

How can I use NetCore as the target?

[image: vs2017 shot]

Comment: What exactly requires you to target .NET Core specifically?

Comment: In your case .Net standard = .Net core

Comment: I have many projects already in Net Core and they are working as expected. Anyway in October they will include the update to the template as stated in the marked answer :)

Comment: @KatLimRuiz It has been available for several days.

Comment: just recently :)

Comment: When VS shows the functions version selector, there is a link at the bottom saying "Making sure the templates are up to date", so you have to let it finish. That seems to make the v2 Core show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now .Net Core TargetFramework is not supported yet.

See the [comment](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/805#issuecomment-425593711) from Azure Functions team.

> We expect to have manual steps that you can try by mid October, and our goal is to have all relevant template/tooling updates complete and deployed by the end of October.

**Update**

v2 Function project with .NET Core TargetFramework(netcoreapp2.1) support has been available, make sure VS >= 15.8(right now 15.8.8) and Azure Function and Web Jobs Tools(On VS menus>Tools>Extensions and Updates) is latest(15.10.2046 right now).

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/805 is now fixed and will be rolled out as part of next release (ETA over next two weeks)